# Serial read operation not getting timed out despite setting SerialPort.ReadTimeout property?

Tags: c#, serial-port, timeout

I am developing an HMI for displaying the data acquired from 8 (Data Acquisition DAQ) cards each having 8 channels through serial port (RS-232).

I want to implement a time-out operation in which the HMI should dispay a message if a particular DAQ card wasn't able to serially send its acquired data within a specific time interval (let's say 20 seconds), and then continue to acquire data from the remaining cards.

For this I am setting the `serialPort.ReadTimeout = 20000` but the operation isn't getting properly timed out as expected.

I am using the BackgroundWorker class to serially send and acquire data of 4000 samples from the cards and it is working fine except for the time-out function. Can anyone point out the issue?

```
//code snippet
    serialP.DataBits = 8;
    serialP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    //serialP.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
    serialP.Parity = Parity.None;
    
    serialP.DataReceived += serialP_DataReceived;

    serialP.WriteTimeout = 20000; 
    serialP.ReadTimeout = 20000;
    
    serialP.Open();            
   
    serialRtx.DoWork += serialRtx_DoWork;            

    if (!serialRtx.IsBusy)
        serialRtx.RunWorkerAsync();

    serialRtx.RunWorkerCompleted += serialRtx_RunWorkerCompleted;
    
}

    private void serialRtx_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
     //Send token packets to DAQ cards sequentially
    }

    private void serialP_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (serialP.BytesToRead > 0)
        {                
            dataBytet1 = serialP.ReadByte();                
            dataByte2 = serialP.ReadByte();                               
                           
            try
            {               
                logData[sample_No, chNo - 1] = ((dataBytet1 * 256) + dataByte2 );                     

                chNo++;

                if (chNo > 8)
                {
                    sample_No++;
                    chNo = 1;
                }

                if (sample_No > 3999)//total 4000 samples of 8 channels
                {
                    cardNo++;
                    sample_No = 0;
                }                
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            { }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a real serial port or emulated because I noticed you have **disabled** _hardware flow control_ and _parity_.  Your `serialP_DataReceived` should be queuing up received data so that another thread can process it, but instead you are processing it on the very thread for the `DataReceived` event.  You're at high risk of data loss.  I/O event handlers should do the minimal of work and return ASAP.   You could run into issues on slower (or at least mildly busy) computers.

Comment: Real Serial port. Haven't run into data loss as of yet but still how should I proceed since I am fairly new to C# programming especially threading. I am already making use of two forms running in parallel, one form acquires and stores serial data to SQL database while a background form has a displayed clock running continuously so two threads are already in use if I am not mistaken.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge if you want to keep on reading data coming from different serial port my advice will be a while 1 loop and keep on reading data without a specific timeout.

Please consider that there can be a byte to byte delay. If your goal is reach the 4000 bytes (I assume this is what you call samples) you'd better keep on reading untill you reached your desired value and then store it for analysis.

Comment: @Rick64 so I should not use the `serialP_DataReceived` event and read all of the data inside the `DoWork` event using a `while(1)` loop instead?

Comment: @Candy this is what I do indeed. I loop in a While 1 loop and get each byte in the buffer. This worked pretty well for me